# Java : javax swing and awt errors

Tags: java, netbeans

So, i have a code in Java that is says its successfull but i get errors that isn't even from my project. I can't do anything about it though.... I've tried importing only the needed parts and i still get same errors. I don't even know what a "container" is. I just finished the Java basics and moved on to this. Now i have a second computer (a macbook air) and it's got same code but it doesn't get any errors at all. Might it be me IDE, Java JDK or something? Or just something weird with the imported files? Thanks.
Code :

```
package windowsgui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WindowsGUI extends JFrame {

private JLabel label;
private JButton button;
private JTextField testfield;

public WindowsGUI() {
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());

    label = new JLabel("This is a label");
    add(testfield);

    button = new JButton("This is a button");
    add(button);

}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    WindowsGUI gui = new WindowsGUI();

    gui.setSize(600, 400);
    gui.setResizable(false);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Error :

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1091)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1003)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:564)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:415)
at windowsgui.WindowsGUI.<init>(WindowsGUI.java:19)
at windowsgui.WindowsGUI.main(WindowsGUI.java:27)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Initialise textfield before you try adding it; call setResizable can change the size of the viewable area, consider using pack instead of setSize and call it after you've called setResizable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label = new JLabel("This is a label");
add(label);

testfield = new JTextField("This is text Field"); 
add(testfield);

button = new JButton("This is a button");
add(button);
```

you are not initialize the testfield, but you try to add the testfield so it gives null pointerException. Solution : initialize the testfield and then add it.

Comment: Perhaps you should initialise the textfield as well? But it's hard to know what the op is trying to do...

Comment: I was 99% sure teh mac code was same... Didn't think it would be that simple... You learn something new every day...